# Sequencing Components in Feature Element

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to replace a file that has been installed by my installer. In the following code the "OneCoreFiles" component should install the files first time( which is working) and the component "ConfigCopyFile" should replace that config file.

But the code is not working as expected. The component 'ConfigCopyFile' is getting executed first and then the 'OnecoreFiles'. I want it to work the other way.

I am still learning WIX and thought that the components in Feature elements are executed in the order in which they are declared.

Code Snippet:

```
<Component Id="ConfigCopyFile" Guid="{98E61055-5A84-4003-90D1-7A67677D7465}">
  <Condition>CONFIGFILEEXISTS</Condition>
  <CopyFile Id="ConfigFileId" SourceProperty="CONFIGFILEEXISTS" DestinationProperty  ="INSTALLDIR"/>
</Component>

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="OneCore Features" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="LogEntries" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="OneCoreFiles" />
        <ComponentRef Id="AppDBConfiguration" />
        <ComponentRef Id="SqlServerConfiguration" />
        <ComponentRef Id="OracleConfiguration" />
        <ComponentRef Id="IISConfiguration" />
        <ComponentRef Id="ConfigCopyFile" />
    </Feature>
```

This must be quite simple to solve. Am I missing something. Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thinking of WiX in the wrong way. It's not a scripting language. It's a way of representing Windows Installer databases which are declarative in nature not imperative.   If I list a bunch of components and files it's non deterministic the order the files will be copied.  I'm only saying that these files need to be installed not how to install them.

Windows Installer does expose sequence tables which drive the order of things ( such as create folders then copy files ) but it doesn't micromanage to the level of copy this file before that file.

[Suggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  InstallExecute Sequence

[InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Table